# Laravel 5.2 fails to read the session cookie

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, xampp, session-cookies

I have a issue in my laravel applications, i'm using XAMPP test run my applications locally on windows machine.

My problem is that Laravel applications get's logout suddendly, this happens very often, if i refresh the same page like 4 , 5 times it get's logged off. but when i check the chrome dev tools Cookies, Laravel_session is still there.

Any idea as to why this could happen?, also, i don't get the same issue when it's hosted online.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with session driver. Because as you said that **if i refresh the same page like 4 , 5 times it get's logged off**, by default session storage is file and you 4-5 time request may messing it up. Here I'm not sure but this stuff may solve your issue.

1. Change `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to `SESSION_DRIVER=database` in `.env`
2. Create session migration with `php artisan session:table` artisan
       code
3. Run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerates the list of all
       classes
4. Run `php artisan migrate` to migrate.

**NOTE:** You can run single migration file by separate with subfolder